# Algunos usuarios no reciven mis notificaciones push, Porque puede ser?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

Estoy en el desarrollo de una aplicación movil android y estoy usando expo y react native, asi tambien estoy usando expo pushNotification y el `expo-server-sdk` para enviar mis notificaciones push de la siguiente manera:

```
console.log("Iniciando");
console.log(event.body);
const data = JSON.parse(event.body)
console.log("Info obtenida");
const expo = new Expo({ accessToken: process.env.expotoken });
console.log("Nuevo cliente expo");
const chunks = expo.chunkPushNotifications([data]);
console.log("Chuncks creados");
const tickets = [];

for (const chunk of chunks) {
  try {
    const ticketChunck = await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync(chunk)
    tickets.push(...ticketChunck)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
console.log("Chuncks ya fueron creados");
let response = ""

for (const ticket of tickets) {
  if (ticket.status === "error") {
    if (ticket.details && ticket.details.error === "DeviceNotRegistered") {
      console.log(`Hubo un error de DeviceNotRegistered - ${ticket.id}`);
      response = "DeviceNotRegistered"
    }
  }
  if (ticket.status === "ok") {
    console.log(`Todo esta ok - ${ticket.id}`);
    response = ticket.id;
  }
}
```

El problema es que estoy viendo que usuarios no reciven notificaciónes despues de un tiempo, el servidor que se encarga de enviar las notificaciónes, no muestra que hubiera un error.

Puede que este realcionado conque los usuarios dejen de usar la app en un lapso de tiempo? podria quedar invernando la aplicación o algo por el estilo y por eso no muestra las notifciaciónes? de ser este el caso que puedo hacer para que no pase este problema?

Comment: Puede ser que esos usuarios desactiven las notificaciones

Comment: Podria ser, pero segun lo que eh investigado, los usuarios no tiene la experiencia para hacerlo

Comment: En mi móvil cada vez que recibo una notificación, al presionarla aparece un botón para dejar de recibir

Comment: Podria ser, pero si se puede dar el caso de que el telefono ponga a la aplicacion en invernación o algo por el estilo?

Comment: Estas notificaciones se envian de forma simultanea a los usuarios? es decir como si enviarás un email para muchas personas, funciona similar tu sistema de notificación esperas que los usuarios reciban la misma notificación? es duda

Comment: Si, se manda en simultaneo a todos los usuarios